# PHP and if not working

Tags: php, if-statement

Hello :) Seems like I am not that good programmer and if doesn't work like it should. Lets see the code.

```
$pkt = mysql_query("SELECT meta_value FROM wp_usermeta WHERE user_id = $user_id AND meta_key='mycred_default'");
if ( $pkt < $price OR $user_id == 0)
{

 $message = 'Sorry, you need more LPoints.';

    echo "<SCRIPT type='text/javascript'>
        alert('$message');
        window.location.replace((\"http://sute.com/rp\"));
    </SCRIPT>";
    mysql_close();
}
```

So pkt is some variable which my user gets. So if he has less points (pkt) than the price he gets message which is in javascript, right? Well... it's not working. Even if my user get more $pkt than $price he still gets that message. But when I change "<" into ">" that means if he get more points than price he can't buy it, right? Well.. not once again. If I set $pkt > $price script is just skipping this if insctruction and behave like it even wasn't there so it's just continue the script. Any idea?

Regreds,
guy with a problem.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: `$pkt` is not a number! "doesn't work like it should", NO, it shouldn't work that way.

Comment: `$pkt` is just returning true or false, not a number.

Comment: You can't just compare a mysql_query object with random variable like that.

Comment: I see. I am really a newbie. Thought if I am getting numbers with phpadmin (now i see it's not really a number) it will work. How can I do it?

Comment: You are executing the query, but not actually fetching the results. See the link PeeHaa posted. This has been asked hundreds of times on this site.

Comment: You can't those variables in the middle of a string.

Comment: when you execute query in phpmyadmin it returns something, but that's not what php function mysql_query() returns. that function returns true or false which means successful execution or not. you have to fetch data out of result-set. look at **any** example at php.net related with mysql.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT meta_value FROM wp_usermeta WHERE user_id = $user_id AND meta_key='mycred_default'");
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
$pkt = $result['meta_value'];
if ( $pkt < $price || $user_id == 0)
{

 $message = 'Sorry, you need more LPoints.';

    echo "<SCRIPT type='text/javascript'>
        alert('$message');
        window.location.replace((\"http://sute.com/rp\"));
    </SCRIPT>";

}
mysql_close();
```

PDO example:

```
<?php
// Initialize the database connection
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.$your_hostname.';dbname=.'$your_db, $user, $pass, 
    array(
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'
    )
);
$sql = "SELECT meta_value FROM wp_usermeta WHERE user_id = :user_id AND meta_key='mycred_default'";

// Create prepared statement
$stm = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stm->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stm->execute();

$pkt = $stm->fetchColumn();
if ( $pkt < $price || $user_id == 0)
{

 $message = 'Sorry, you need more LPoints.';

    echo "<SCRIPT type='text/javascript'>
        alert('$message');
        window.location.replace((\"http://sute.com/rp\"));
    </SCRIPT>";

}
```

Comment: At third line of your code snippet. You should use isset around $result['meta_value'] to avoid null exception.

Comment: Alexey, also you must close mysql connection even conditions return false, plz don't make silly mistakes.

Comment: Thanks you, working! I see that people wanted me to read about it, but thanks for that code. I'll study about fetch_assoc function. I'll accept your answer in next 5 mins (got block).

Comment: >At third line of your code snippet. You should use isset around $result['meta_value'] to avoid null exception. 
Exception? Because of what? Do you mean warning?

Comment: >Alexey, also you must close mysql connection even conditions return false, plz don't make silly mistakes.
Yes, you're right, I did not pay attention to it, because it shows the general principle, but of course you're right.

Comment: @user3565273 better don't study `mysql_*` functions at all. start using (learning) `mysqli_*` or `PDO`! Soon there will be no `mysql_*` functions.

Comment: Why did you change OR into ||? It's same thing? I'll accept your answer in 1 minute :)

Comment: Yes, It's same thing.

Comment: To be honest I am not sure why, but yeah. I am reading about mysqli but when I use it I am getting errors that mysqli is a bad function or something. Could you tell me why?